Spring-Boot 3.4 not loading log4j2.xml file
I am trying to leverage log4j2 within my spring-boot app. Long term the goal is to leverage some of the DB appenders that log4j2 supports, but initially just trying to make sure it's loading log4j instead of logback.
I have my log4j2.xml file located in my src/main/resources folder.
Im using gradle for my build and have the following config
implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind'
    implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-yaml'
    implementation 'org.postgresql:postgresql'
    implementation 'org.springframework.data:spring-data-mongodb:4.4.0'
    implementation 'org.springframework.data:spring-data-commons:3.4.0'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator:3.4.0'
    implementation 'org.mongodb:mongodb-driver-sync:5.2.1'
    implementation 'org.mongodb:mongodb-driver-core:5.2.1'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.11.0'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation "me.paulschwarz:spring-dotenv:4.0.0"
    implementation 'org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-mongodb:2.24.3'
    implementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-log4j2:3.4.0"
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    testRuntimeOnly 'org.junit.platform:junit-platform-launcher'

    modules {
        module("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging") {
            replacedBy("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-log4j2", "Use Log4j2 instead of Logback")
        }
    }

The modules component at the bottom seems to be correctly replacing all instances of spring-boot-start-logging with spring-boot-starter-log4j2. I was able to verify that with the output of the ./gradlew dependencies which produced this output for every line that had spring-boot-starter-logging.
|    |    |    +--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging:3.3.5 -> org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-log4j2:3.4.0
|    |    |    |    +--- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-slf4j2-impl:2.24.1 -> 2.23.1
|    |    |    |    |    +--- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:2.23.1
|    |    |    |    |    +--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:2.0.9 -> 2.0.16
|    |    |    |    |    \--- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-core:2.23.1
|    |    |    |    |         \--- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:2.23.1
|    |    |    |    +--- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-core:2.24.1 -> 2.23.1 (*)
|    |    |    |    \--- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-jul:2.24.1 -> 2.23.1
|    |    |    |         \--- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:2.23.1

I also verified that I don't have any instances of slf4j implementations other than the one shown above from log4j2.
When I run the app, the log4j2.xml file is completely ignored. I know this because it references an invalid path for where to put the FileAppender output that shoudl throw an error (this was done on purpose to make testing easier).
If I try to force the loading of the file by setting
logging:
   config: classpath:log4j2.xml

in my application.yml file, I just get a new block at the top of my console on execution complaining about logback-classic and then I get the SPRING ANSI art and that's it. No other calls to the Log4j impl actually come through and no files are ever created.
I feel like there has to be something simple I am missing as all of the articles I can find seem to imply that I have done all of the correct things to make this work, but I sure can't find the issue.
I am expecting to get an error because log4j2.xml is attempting to write to a log file located at c:/temp which is an invalid path on my Mac.
I also attempted to try using the log4j2.yml file to see if that was working, and what I get when I do that via the
logger:
   config: classpath:log4j2.yml

entry is an error message stating that only XML formats are valid here.

"I know this because it references an invalid path for where to put the FileAppender output that shoudl throw an error"—if your configuration is invalid an error will be logged not thrown and the file appender will be ignored. Can you run your application with -Dlog4j2.statusLoggerLevel=DEBUG or -Dlog4j2.debug to check which config file is picked?
